# How do I import a module into a different file, in the same directory?

Tags: python, class, import, module

In one of my folders/directories, I have a module named "restaurant_class.py" with a class that I am trying to import into a different module named "restaurant_instance.py"

`from restaurant_class import Restaurant`

In the same directory I do have a blank file named `__init__.py`.

Every time I try to import the module and class, it keeps giving me the error

`no module named 'restaurant_class'`

How do I import a module and/or class from a module that I created?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. In my File Explorer to locate the directory, I was in the wrong directory. The files are placed correctly, just had the wrong directory pulled up in Spyder.